# How to pass object whose constructor consist of one argument to a function in C++?

Tags: c++

I have defined a class B, whose constructor accept object of other class(class A) as parameter. Class A constructor also consist of parameter. I am getting error as described below. What is the problem here?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    int val;
    A(int val){
        this->val=val;
    }
};
class B{
    A a;
    B(A& x){
        a=x;
    }
};
int main(){
    A tempa(3);
    B tempb(tempa);
}
```

Error:

```
temp.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B(A&)’:
temp.cpp:13:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
temp.cpp:13:9: note: candidates are:
temp.cpp:6:2: note: A::A(int)
temp.cpp:6:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
temp.cpp:3:7: note: A::A(const A&)
temp.cpp:3:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: This question should not be voted to close because of "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".  Maybe it's a dupe, but it's not that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way to explicitly initialize a data member is in the constructor initialization list. Once you are in the body of the constructor, the member has been initialized, and all you can do is modify it. In your case, since you are not doing this, the data member would bet implicitly *default constructed*, but `A` does not have a default constructor.

You need to use the appropriate constructor in the constructor initialization list:

```
B(A& x) : a(x)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the corrected code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    int val;
public:
    A(int val){
        this->val=val;
    }
};
class B{
    A a;
    public:
    B(A& x):a(x) {
    }
};
int main(){
    A tempa(3);
    B tempb(tempa);
}
```

Corrections are:

```
1. Both Constructors of A and B should be public
2. Instead of assignment, let B constructor call A's copy constructor
```

Comment: That assignment operator just mimics the one the compiler gives `A`. Why not let the compiler do the work and ensure it's correct? And what if a default constructor for `A` is undesirable?

Comment: Point taken @chris, edited my code

Comment: This is "corrected" only to the point that it does sort of work--but it's still not written "correctly" for most definitions of the word. You really should use a member initializer list in `A::A(int)` (and when you do assignments, `this->` is almost always unnecessary noise).

Comment: where is the copy constructor of A defined?

Comment: @canoe, copy constructor is compiler generated one